# Установить другую копию программы

Tags: ios, qt, iphone

Проект на Qt для iOs
Есть ли возможность поставить вторую копию программы на iPhone? Какие параметры проекта нужно для этого поменять?

Если меняю в plist файле поле CFBundleIdentifier, то сборка накрывается:

Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching the bundle identifier “com.XXXXXX.ios” were found.

p.s. Если меняю CFBundleName, то при установке, копия программы с прежним именем сносится.

Comment: Повангую... название?

Comment: Копаюсь в plist файле. Если менять CFBundleName, то при установке, копия программы с прежним именем сносится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменять надо в plist `Bundle Identifier (CFBundleIdentifier)` ну и сгенерировать новый profile, поскольку это уже другое приложение

Comment: Да, этим дело и закончилось. Плюс к этому нужен был другой iOs App ID.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать провижен для множества bundleID (вроде "com.app.*). Тогда сможешь использовать любой bundleID с приставкой com.app